# 8 bit serial adder with accumulator

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I am writing a VHDL code to impelemt 8 bit serial adder with accumulator.
When i do simulation, the output is always zeros! And some times it gives me the same number but with a shift ! 
 I dont know what is the problem, i tried to put A,B as inout but didnt work as well. Can anybody help please.

This is the code:

```
entity SA is

Port ( st : in std_logic;
        A,B: inout std_logic_vector ( 7 downto 0);
       clk : in std_logic;
       acc : out bit_vector(7 downto 0)); end SA; 
architecture Behavioral of SA is

 signal ps,ns: integer range 0 to 7;

signal C,D: bit_vector (7 downto 0);


signal ci,ciplus,si,sh:bit;

begin

 si<=A(0) xor B(0) xor ci ;
 ciplus <=(A(0) and B(0)) or (A(0) and ci ) or ( B(0) and ci );


   process(ps,st)
   begin
  case ps  is
  when 0=> if(st='0')then 
      ns<=0;
      else
       ns<=1;
       sh<='1';
       end if;
       when 1 to 6 => sh<='1';
       ns<= ps+1;
        when 7=> sh<='1';
        ns <=0;
        end case;
        end process;


        process(clk)
        begin
        if(clk 'event and clk ='1')then
             ps <= ns;
        ci<= ciplus;
                end if;
        if(sh='1') then 
        C<=si & A(7 downto 1) ;
         D<=B(0) & B(7 downto 1);
        end if;

        end process;

        acc<= C;

        end Behavioral;
```

`

Comment: Please clean up your code with proper indenting.

Answer (score 1):

Your second process is written incorrectly. Prior to writing a process, you should always decide whether the process is sequential or combinatorial, and then write the process accordingly.

To help you write your code, especially when starting out with hardware description languages, please please please *always* draw a block diagram first, and then describe that block diagram using VHDL.

As it is, your second process:

1. Mixes combinatorial and sequential logic.
2. Is missing signals in the process sensitivity list.
3. Generates a latch because C and D are not assigned in all paths through the process.

Your first process has similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

try initializing ps and ns see if that does the trick I am on my phone now so i cant simulate to help but usualy my problems in VHDL design are form uninitilized integers

```
signal ps,ns: integer range 0 to 7:=0;
```

you might want to check your warnings list see if that helps

Comment: In VHDL signals (and variables) always initialise to the leftmost value in their range, so the `:=0` is not required in this case as `0 is already the left-most element.